# new heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed"

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm getting the above error from heroku. I've tried several of the solutions including: updating the engine in package.json for both the node version and npm, as well as using the heroku restart command. I also made sure that the port on my DB config wasn't hard coded as some answers suggested. Here is my config:

```
    var url = process.env.DATABASEURL || "mongodb://localhost/roam- 
    hub";
    mongoose.connect(url);
```

The error also points to my dotenv file, which is connected and configured correctly I think? Everything works fine on my local environment. Does anyone have a new suggestion on how to troubleshoot this problem?

```
    throw err;
    2018-09-12T12:22:20.970580+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
    2018-09-12T12:22:20.970582+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2018-09-12T12:22:20.970583+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find 
    module 'dotenv'
    2018-09-12T12:22:20.970585+00:00 app[web.1]: at 
    Function.Module._resolveFilename 
    (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:594:15)
```

Here is my package.json file:

```
    {
    "name": "roam-app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "engines": {
    "node": "10.5.0",
    "npm": "6.2.0"
    },
    "description": "central app for all things Roam",
    "main": "app.js",
    "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node app.js"
    },
    "author": "*",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cloudinary": "^1.11.0",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "connect-timeout": "^1.9.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "method-override": "^2.3.10",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "mongoose": "^5.1.5",
    "multer": "^1.3.1",
    "nodemailer": "^4.6.7",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-local-mongoose": "^5.0.0",
    "request": "^2.87.0",
    "session": "^0.1.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^6.0.0"
    }
    }
```

I started getting this error after I changed some basic HTML files and pushed to heroku. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: in witch place do you put your .env variable ?

Comment: Alex had the solution below. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stacktrace is telling you what is going wrong, most importantly:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'dotenv'
```

I suspect that you're doing a `npm install --production` and its installing only the dependencies listed under your `dependencies` in your package.json whereas `dotenv` is listed as a `devDependency` and hence not being installed. It's not complaining about not being able to find your `.env` file, its complaining that it can't resolve the `dotenv` module.

Considering what `dotenv` does, it should be a production dependency and should be moved from `devDependencies` into `dependencies`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help Alex! It worked immediately.

Comment: No problem, happy to help!